# Why does only one value gets return in NodeRED function node?

Tags: node-red, kepserverex

I have a NodeRED flow which has a function node and my code is following

```
var left = { payload : msg.payload.readResults[0].v };
var right = { payload : msg.payload.readResults[1].v };
node.warn(left);
node.warn(right);
if(left || right)
{
    return [left,right];
}
```

Here I'm trying to get the both `left` and `right` outputs. The `node.warn(left)` and `node.warn(right)` tags give the outputs correctly but in the real `return` statement it outputs only `left` value when I have `return[left,right]`. When I have `return left,right` it returns `right` value.

How to get the both `left` and `right` values using `return` statement? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Why not just keep them in the msg object? Node-RED is all about passing msg around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out, posting if incase anyone interested!

```
var left = {payload : msg.payload.readResults[0].v };
var right = {payload : msg.payload.readResults[1].v };


return [[left,right]];
```

Comment: This is because when you return an array, the messages are written to the function nodes outputs based on array order, so with just a single dimension array `right` gets sent to the 2nd output (which doesn't exist). with to 2d array both get written to the first output